# spring mvc RequestMapping and redirecting to view

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I have a code in MyController

```
 @RequestMapping("/hello.jsp")
    public void handleRequest() {
        System.out.println("hello.jsp");
        logger.info("Returning hello view");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello2")
    public ModelAndView hello2() {
        System.out.println("123");
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello2", "message", message);
    }
```

In dispatcher-servlet.xml I have:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">       
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

In the end I have:

```
~8080/hello2.htm - OK
~8080/hello.htm  - NOT OK, aloso I tried: hello.jsp, hello; moved hello.jsp to /WEB-INF/jsp/ and to/WEB-INF/ - no effect 


1.hello2() is working well, and redirecting to the hello2.jsp
2.hello() is NOT working, and NOT redirecting
```

Before putting "viewResolver" into dispatcher-servlet.xml I had opposite behaviour - hello() was working hello2() was not. [but then I had all my jps in WEB-INF folder]

What is the reason?

my web.xml consists this:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of '/hello.jsp' - it was trying to find '/hello.jsp.jsp', since I've defined 'viewResolver' with: suffix" value=".jsp".

And before: without 'viewResolver', it was behaving by some default logic, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are returning  `void` instead of the view name.

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String handleRequest() {
    System.out.println("hello.jsp");
    logger.info("Returning hello view");
    return("hello");
}
```

Comment: it was because of '/hello.jsp' it was tried to find '/hello.jsp.jsp' file because I defined 'viewResolver' and used suffix: suffix" value=".jsp".